# Getting Post, Page, CPT and Archive page IDs using URL

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

I am currently using url_to_postid() to get the ID from the URL which is later used to get the other language page in WPML using that ID.

```
$last_visited_id = url_to_postid( $last_visited_url );
```

This also works fine for getting Post ID, Page ID, and CPT ID. But the issue is getting the archive page URLs like Blog Page, Shop page, etc.

As url_to_postid() function returns 0 for [www.domainname.com/blog/](http://www.domainname.com/blog/) or [www.domainname.com/shop/](http://www.domainname.com/shop/) pages, I cannot get the respective language pages in WPML.

I tried using the below function as well. Here the issue is, that I don't have the POST TYPE value and also this doesn't work for the BLOG Archive or Shop Archive page.

```
get_page_by_path($page_path, $output, $post_type);
```

Comment: Perhaps `get_queried_object` is more helpful? You could use the `instanceof` operator to check what type of class it returned, and proceed from there.

Comment: Can you help me with more details maybe?

Comment: The function can return several object types, among them WP_Term, WP_Post_Type, WP_Post. So if you check for any of those, and maybe combine with some other methods (like is_archive()), you should be able to determine the necessary ID. (But doesn't provide WPML any functionality for such a purpose already?)

Comment: Nothing as fas as I checked.